# Can I re-use XSL templates with unique XML content?

Tags: xml, xslt

Maybe there is a better way of describing my problem...

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

Take this:

```
<inc_3c>
    <Title>This is 3C</Title>
    <Subtitle>Lorem ipsum dolor consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada.</Subtitle>
    <Description>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada. Nullam vel justo a dui pellentesque euismod. Integer eu pulvinar dolor.</Description>
    <Class>priceWrapper</Class>
    <Price>$00.00</Price>
    <Url>Url</Url>
    <Image>apple-tv.png</Image>
</inc_3c>
```

and copy it like so:

```
<inc_3c-copy>
    <Title>This is 3C</Title>
    <Subtitle>Lorem ipsum dolor consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada.</Subtitle>
    <Description>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada. Nullam vel justo a dui pellentesque euismod. Integer eu pulvinar dolor.</Description>
    <Class>priceWrapper</Class>
    <Price>$00.00</Price>
    <Url>Url</Url>
    <Image>apple-tv.png</Image>
</inc_3c-copy>
```

- inc_3c = would populate content on page#1
- inc_3c-copy = would populate content on page#2

might even be a scenario where inc_3c and inc_3c-copy live on the same page.

hopefully I wouldn't need to create another XSL page.

this would have to be non-coder proof.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, very short and easy solution based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- *the overriding of the identity rule*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Learn about using the [identity rule/template](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) and overriding it. This alone is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern**.

In your case we use this design pattern to override just the top element in the following way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/inc_3c">
  <inc_3c-copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </inc_3c-copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<inc_3c>
    <Title>This is 3C</Title>
    <Subtitle>Lorem ipsum dolor consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada.</Subtitle>
    <Description>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada. Nullam vel justo a dui pellentesque euismod. Integer eu pulvinar dolor.</Description>
    <Class>priceWrapper</Class>
    <Price>$00.00</Price>
    <Url>Url</Url>
    <Image>apple-tv.png</Image>
</inc_3c>
```

**the wanted, corresct result is produced**:

```
<inc_3c-copy>
   <Title>This is 3C</Title>
   <Subtitle>Lorem ipsum dolor consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada.</Subtitle>
   <Description>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis consequat malesuada. Nullam vel justo a dui pellentesque euismod. Integer eu pulvinar dolor.</Description>
   <Class>priceWrapper</Class>
   <Price>$00.00</Price>
   <Url>Url</Url>
   <Image>apple-tv.png</Image>
</inc_3c-copy>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I'm going to give this thing a shot. I'll praise you shortly!